# Convert from System.Collections.Hashtable to specific JSON format is not working in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable

Below is the type of source object:
[image]

my hashtable value are as below:

[image]

and I am trying to get JSON in below format:

[image]

my hashtable value are as below:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                              
----                           -----                                                                                                                                              
modesite                       {10000, 10001...}                                                                                                                    
sites                          {11800, 11900...}                                                                                                                    
Tsitesata                      {12000, 12001...}                                                                                                                    
direct                         {13002, 13003...}
```

and I am trying to get JSON in below format:

```
{
    modesite: {
        Ids: [
            10000, 10001, 10002, .... , 10030, 10032 
        ]
    },
    sites: {
        Ids: [
            11800, 11801, ...., 11809
        ]
    },
    Tsitesata: {
        Ids: [
            12000, 12001, ...., 12030
        ]
    },
    direct: {
        Ids: [
            13002, 13003, ...., 13015
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is **incomplete** as it does not contain any code (in particular, where the `$exampleObj` comes from?). However, you could either accept the [toastifer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372882/3439404), or try the following:

```
$exampleObj = @{
    modesite = @( 10000, 10001);
    sites    = @( 11800, 11900);
    Tsitesata= @( 12000, 12001);
    direct   = @( 13002, 13003);
}
$desiredObj = foreach ($key in $exampleObj.Keys) {
    @{ $key = @{ Ids = $exampleObj.$Key }}
}
$desiredObj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the array directly under the key.  Store it in ANOTHER hash table with the key 'Ids'.

```
   $exampleObj=@{
     modesite=@{ids=@(1,2,3)}
     sites=@{ids=@(4,5,6)}
   }
```

You can also create an object with ConvertFrom-Json.  Plug in your desired output, and you'll be able to see how to structure the object.